# A function that converts two unit interval numbers to another unit interval number

Tags: algorithm, math

I need a function that takes two parameters as input: `0<=a<=1` and `0<=b<=1`.

The output is another number `c` which falls in the interval `[0,1]` too. `c` must be greater than or equal to both `a` and `b`. The function must be monotonic as well, so if `a2>a1` and `b2>=b1`, `c2` must be greater than `c1`, unless `c2=c1=1`.

Thanks you guys, I've figured out a simple solution myself. simply make `c=a+b-ab`, all requirements are met.

Comment: There is no such function. If `a` equals `1`, there is no `c` greater than `a` in the interval `[0,1]`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant greater or equal than. If `a` is equal to 1 of course `c` should be 1 too.

Comment: I rather fear that all that's going to happen here is a series of comments/answers pointing out that this can't be done, each followed by a subtle change in requirements. Perhaps if you told us the actual problem that gave rise to this need, we'd be able to help with *that* ?

Comment: If you have an answer (which by your edit, it appears that you do), please post it *as* an answer (and then, when you can, accept it as the answer). That's how things work on SO so that we know which questions still need answers.

Comment: Well for your information I'm a new user so can't add my own answer until 8 hours later. I will add my own answer when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another proposal:

```
1-(1-a)(1-b)=a+b-ab=a+b(1-a)=b+a(1-b)
```

is, by the first form, inside [0,1], by the third greater than a for b<1, and by the fourth greater than b for a<1.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement that **c** is always greater than **a** and **b** cannot be met since **a** and **b** are allowed to be `1.0` and **c** cannot be greater than this.

Also the requirement that

> The function must be monotonic as well, so if a2>a1 and b2>=b1, c2
>   must be greater than c1.

is bad formed. This is not a definition of monotonicity of a multivariate function. Nevertheless, I give an example how to fulfill

> The function must be monotonic as well, so if a2>a1 and b2>=b1, c2
>   must be greater than c1 (or c = 1.0).

condition too, in function (3).

Here I assume that **c** is greater **or equal** to both parameters:

(1)

```
double f( double a, double b) {
  if ( (a == 1.0) || (b == 1.0)) return 1.0;
  return max(a,b) + (1.0 - max(a,b)) / 2;
}
```

You can eventually specify epsilon to make accuracy explicit.

(2)

```
double f( double a, double b, double epsilon) {
  if ( (a == 1.0) || (b == 1.0)) return 1.0;
  return min( 1.0, max(a,b) + epsilon);
}
```

---

Function that satisfies also  (bad worded monotonicity)

> The function must be monotonic as well, so if a2>a1 and b2>=b1, c2
>   must be greater than c1.

(3)

```
double f( double a, double b, double epsilon) {
  if ( (a == 1.0) || (b == 1.0)) return 1.0;
  double distance = 1.0 - max(a,b);
  return 1.0 - distance + max( epsilon, a * distance);
}
```

Comment: return max(a,b) + (1.0 - max(a,b)) / 2; if a>b then no matter what b's value is, it always returns the same thing.

Comment: why it is not correct? This is in line what you have described in question

Comment: "so if a2>a1 and b2>=b1, c2 must be greater than c1." In your case c2=c1

Comment: @user2894968 this is bad formed, this is not multivariate monotonicity, however I have also provided a remedy for this

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function possible. For `a=0, b=1`, the only valid output would be `c=1`. However, if `a2=0.5, b2=1`, then again the only valid output is `c2=1`, violating your second requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One function to consider is *bit interleaving* or Morton numbers.

Example:

```
 a = 0.1 0 0 1 = 9/16 = 0.5625
 b = 0. 0 1 1 0 = 6/16 = 0.3750
 c = 0.10010110 = 150/256 = 0.5859375   c >= a, c >= b

 a = 1-epsilon = 0.1111111
 b = 1-epsilon = 0.1111111 --> c = 0.11111111 = 1-epsilon
```

The numbers *a*, *b* must be sorted however, i.e. *a* > *b*